# Facebook and Twitter share buttons not working

Tags: plugins, facebook, twitter, plugin-jetpack

I have jetpack enabled on wordpress 3.4.2 install. However the Facebook and Twitter share buttons don't work.

Whenever one clicks on the Facebook or the Twitter button, a new window pops-up with the same page and the share=facebook at the end of the URL

Here is the blog with the issue:
http://karba.la

Answer (score 1):

There is a jQuery event hooked to that link.  Here is the function that is called whenever you click one of the sharing links:

```
function (){
    window.open( jQuery(this).attr( 'href' ), 'wpcomtwitter', 'menubar=1,resizable=1,width=600,height=350' );
    return false;
}
```

This is added by the JetPack plugin and will attempt to open a dialog window with the url `http://karba.la/?share=twitter&nb=1` in a window called `wpcomtwitter`.  The window is opening, but something is breaking inside the window such that it doesn't redirect to Twitter appropriately.

The thing is, opening a developer console on your site yields several hundred JavaScript errors, so *something* is intercepting the script callbacks and preventing it from working.  We have no way to tell what exactly is going on, though.

Try disabling everything *but* JetPack and see if that fixes it.